# SQL Developer: Drag-Drop Column Names into Worksheet

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

My question is about Oracle SQL Developer IDE.

I remember there was an option in Query Results pane to drag and drop the column names into Worksheet. So you don't need to type the column name manually.

Today, I see that the option is used to move columns (as shown in the picture).

Is there an option to bring back column name drag-drop?

*Note: There is a right option to copy column name but drag-drop is much more convenient.*

[image]

Comment: I don't remember ever being able to do this...I know you can DnD column names from the table viewer...

Comment: does the insight feature not give you what you want? ctrl+spacebar should give you a list of columns from your query in a SELECT, WHERE, ORDER clause, etc